# Does a fast gets break when eating unintentionally?

Tags: practical-islam, sawm

Salaam , I was on my fast today but nobody knew it . I just kept it secretly for some specific reason . An hour before the maghrib prayer my mother phoned me and and told me to come to my aunt's house cause she has gone to pay her a visit . I drive to my aunt's house . When I entered the house , my aunt showed some formality and she made me to eat a cake and drink some juice I unintentionally drank it . But I swear I didn't put anything in my mouth before maghrib's adhaan , Is my roza(fast) vaild ?

Comment: Your question title asks about whether fast is broken if one eats unintentionally while you say you didn't put anything in your mouth this seems confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, your fast is valid.**

[See the hadith from Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/47)

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If somebody eats something **forgetfully** while he
>   is **fasting**, then he should complete his fast, for Allah has made him
>   eat and drink."

I don't think you need any more proof.

Answer (score 1):

> The Prophet(pbuh) said: “Whoever forgets he is fasting and eats or drinks, let him complete his fast for it is Allaah Who has fed him and given him to drink.”

So you don't need to make up for that day of fasting.

But make sure you'll be more conscious when fasting next ramadan in sha Allah.

Source: https://islamqa.info/en/50041

Comment: So it means my roza was still on

Comment: Roza = fasting so yeah.